# Testing credit card payment method in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

How Can I order without payment to check my own store? I added few thing and really want to check from customers perspective as well as how I receive data in Order form?

Comment: Any idea of the payment method you would like to use (for your customers)?

Comment: Any payment method, Paypal/Credit Card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test payment, you should go for a **sandbox mode**.

Here are the main steps to follow:

1. Register a Paypal Sandbox Account
2. Set a WooCommmerce Paypal Sandbox Account
3. Test the payment by Paypal Sandbox

You can find details on this page:
[How To Test WooCommerce Payment By PayPal Sandbox](https://www.woobeginner.com/woocommerce-paypal-sandbox/)